# The centripetal acceleration is directly or inversely proportional to the radius?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

In uniform circular movement, the centripetal acceleration is given by

$$a_c=\omega^2 R$$ and is also given by $$a_c = \frac{v_T^2}{R}$$

If we keep $V_T$(tangent velocity) and $\omega$ constant, is $a_c$ directly or inverse proportional to the radius?

My argument was that it is directly proportional to the radius, because a greater radius will cause an increase in tangential velocity and therefore the centripetal acceleration necessary to keep the particle in circular motion will be greater.

However, I am not sure of my argument.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is centripetal force related to radius?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136994/)

Answer (score 2):

The centripetal acceleration $a_c$ is given by $\dfrac{{V_t}^2}{R}$ not by $\dfrac{V_t}{R}$ and the tangential velocity by $R\omega$. Now if you keep $V_t$ constant it does not mean  $\omega$ as well as $R$ are constants but the product i.e. $R \omega$ is constant. In this situation the acceleration is not constant.

Along with $V_t$ if you keep $\omega$ to be constant then it would mean $R$ is also constant. Now coming to the part of proportionality,  keeping $\omega$ fixed, we see that $a_c$ is directly proportional to Radius.

Answer (score 0):

So it depends.

Case 1:
$a_c$ is directly proportional to $R$ if and only if when you change $R$ you keep $\omega$ constant.

Example: You should think of an object which is attached to a ceiling fan. the ceiling fan has a strong motor and always rotated with constant $\omega$. In this case $a_c$ is directly proportional to $R$ i.e. if you increase $R$ the motor has to use more force to keep $\omega$ constant. (Note ,$\omega$ is constant, but changing $R$ results is changing $V_T$.)

Case 2:
$a_c$ is inversely proportional to $R$ if and only if when you change $R$ you keep $V_T$ constant.

Example: Let's say you have a massless rotating disk. $\omega$ can be manually adjusted. You place an object at $R$ on the rotating disk. you measure the $V_T$ of the object. then you increase $R$, but you manually decrease $\omega$ until the object has $V_T$ again. In this case $a_c$ decreases with increasing $R$.

Case 3 (the interesting case):
What if there is no motor to keep the $\omega$ or $V_T$ constant? A disk is free to rotate with some initial $\omega$ and there is an object on it. you move the object and measure everything.

Initial condition is $\omega_i$ and $R_i$, then we change the distance to $R_f$. We assume that momentum is conserved.

Conservation of momentum:

$L_i = L_f$

$\omega_i I_i = \omega_f I_f$

where $I$ is the moment of inertia.

$\omega_i m R_i^2= \omega_f m R_f^2$

$\omega_i R_i^2 = \omega_f R_f^2$

$\omega_f = \omega_i \frac{R_i^2}{R_f^2}  $

Now, let's look at $a_c$'s.

$a_{cf} = \omega_f^2 R_f$

$a_{cf} = \Big( \omega_i \frac{R_i^2}{R_f^2} \Big)^2 R_f$

$a_{cf} = \omega_i^2 R_i \Big(\frac{R_i}{R_f} \Big)^3$

$a_{cf} = a_{ci} \Big(\frac{R_i}{R_f} \Big)^3$

Now you can see how $a_c$'s are related  to each other.